# PHP Julian date function

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon, julian-date

So i have this function that converts date to julian date. It works as excpected, but the result it returns is the timestamp of today in julian date - today 12/08/2022 = 122223

```
function data_giuliana()
{
 $anno = Carbon::now()->format('y'); // 2 digit year

 $timestamp = Carbon::now()->firstOfYear()->timestamp;
 $yearFirstDay = floor($timestamp / 86400);
 $today = ceil(Carbon::now()->timestamp / 86400);
 $giorno = ($today - $yearFirstDay);

 $data_giuliana = "1" . $anno . $giorno;

 return $data_giuliana;
}
```

I'm trying to edit it so that it recieves the param of a date and converts it

What i'm trying is something like this:

```
function data_giuliana($date) {
  // conversion logic of $date
  // return $converted date
}
```

Let's say i would like to convert to a julian date `1997/07/07` how should be the function logic? in julian date should be `097188`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I am mistaken or I got it wrong but isn't there PHP function for exactly what you need?

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.juliantojd.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-to-jd.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.jdtojulian.php

Comment: Unfortunately those functions do not work, i mean they return another result, a 7 characters result. I need 6 numbers because Oracle JDE accepts only that type of data

Comment: then you can use the same code you are using for today but instead of Carbon::now use Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.